# Tablet Setup Automation

Tags: android, automation, installation, settings

I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to programming and I had a question about setting up a program that acts like a setup script for android tablets. What I would like to be able to do is connect a tablet via usb and run a program that can install some apks (from the pc) and change some system settings on the tablet.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm not sure where to start. Looking up this topic online has shown me snippets of what I need, but nothing puts it all together, and I don't have much of a clue on how to test this with an emulated device.

I did setup Android studio, I setup eclipse to run android projects and Xamarin in c#. If I could get any advice on where to start and where I can learn more I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: it is not Android progrramming question. You need a desktop app, which works through ADB

Comment: Ah, ok. Can I make this sort of program in C#, or is done through another language?

Comment: any language will do. You will need to call command line commands, like `adb install app.apk` to install the app

Comment: Ok cool, do I need any specific packages to execute these commands?

Comment: first you have to find out which commands you need to execute. `adb` is a binary (exe) file from android platform tools.

Comment: alright gotcha, I'll take a look into adb, thanks for your help!